# Moving rows to columns through loops (pandas, python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am wanting to move year code to columns, and then move the corresponding population to rows in the columns. I think that I have the first steps but I get lost after the what I have listed below.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cities = row['City']
    year = row['Year_code']
    
    df.loc[index, "2010"] = df['Population'][0]
    print(df)



      Year_code  Population                     City State   area    2010
0              1      115848      Ames, IA Metro Area  None  11180  115848
1              2      115850      Ames, IA Metro Area  None  11180  
2              3      115925      Ames, IA Metro Area  None  11180  
3              4      117424      Ames, IA Metro Area  None  11180  
4              5      118139      Ames, IA Metro Area  None  11180
```

Comment: please share the code of what you have tried.

Comment: I added the code to the post. Apologies this was my first time posting on here, and thought the screenshot would post.

Answer (score 0):

You can "pivot" the year code into the columns like so:

`pivot = df.pivot(index=['City', 'State', 'Area'], columns='Year_code', values='Population')`

If you then want to go back to the regular 0, 1, 2... index, you can use
`pivot = pivot.reset_index()`